# Air travel using foreign passport with maiden name

Tags: passports, international-travel, us-residents, thai-citizens

My wife recently got her Green Card and we would like to travel from the United States to Thailand and back in a few months.

Her Thai Passport has her maiden name and her Green Card has her married name.

Is that a problem or not? What documentation would she need to enter Thailand, and then to reenter the United States? Would traveling with our marriage certificate be sufficient?

Should plane tickets be purchased under her maiden name or her married name?

Any information, relevant links, or directions would be appreciated.

Comment: Ticket requires her name of the Passport. The green card is only for entry into the USA.

Comment: @SheikPaul with the passport and green card and evidence of the name change, the tickets could probably be in either name. (The green card is also necessary to get a *boarding pass* for a flight to the US, after all.)  Anyone investigating the name discrepancy might well wonder why the ticket is in the traveler's maiden name when that is not her *current* name.

Answer (score 4):

Per US [Customs & Border Patrol (CBP)](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1209/~/us-citizens%2Flawful-permanent-residents-name-does-not-match-documents)

> Can I travel if my name has changed due to marriage, divorce, etc.,
>   and my documents are in my old name?
>
> Lawful Permanent Residents (LPR): LPR's who change their name due to
>   marriage or because of any other circumstance **may travel using your
>   LPR Card (US Green Card; I551) in your prior name provided you bring
>   proof of your name progression such as; a marriage certificate**, a
>   divorce decree or court documents showing a legal name change.
>
> Please check with the country(s) you are traveling to for their entry
>   requirements.

In your case her country will not have any problems since she will be entering on her country's passport